# Java technique which allow switch client to correct work servers

Tags: java, tcpserver

I am Java developer, and I never worked with server applications.

Now I plan to write some distributed server with workflow like this:

1. Client(desktop application) logins to core(auth) server.
2. Core server chooses one of the work servers. And redirect client to this server.
3. Work server is a specific application that can be hosted on another machine.
4. Work server can redirect client to core server, and we can repeat step 2.

So, if I'd like to implement this for myself there will be some demon-application on every real host-server, that will communicate with core server, and run another demons as every work server.) It's real to write this by hand, but I'm worried about security and performance of such solution.

But I'm pretty sure, there must be something, much more better for such workflow. Or, better workflow, for achieve similar results.

I ask you give me right direction for my investigation. I looked to JavaEE and Spring Framework, but there aree too big, and I don't sure, they contain exactly what I need.

Many thanks for any useful information!

Comment: I recommend checking out this tutorial on the java.nio package.  It seems similar to what you're looking for.  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html

Comment: Thank you @Martin, yes NIO is a good low-level solution. But I asked, first of all about infrastructure, that allows creation, distribution and communication between servers, hosted on different physical servers. I think, there will be smth for achieve transparent interaction between client and work servers. But, maybe I'll write it manually, it's not too difficult, as I see at first glance.